# Always Display Child Pages on Parent Pages and Child Pages PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my code. What is the best way to display all sub pages for a parent page regardless of whether or not you are viewing the parent or child pages? If a different parent is chosen, then the child pages of the previously selected parent should be hidden.

All pages have a id vairable in the URL that is available using $_GET['id'].

My MYSQL DB looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

With the code I have currently, the child pages display if you are on the parent page, but as soon as you jump to any of the child pages, the child pages disappear.

```
$gParents = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db.pages WHERE parent = 0');

while($parents = mysql_fetch_assoc($gParents))
{
    echo '<a href="?id='.$parents['id'].'">'.$parents['title'].'</a><br />';

    $qChilds = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db.pages WHERE parent = '.$parents['id'].' AND parent = '.$_GET['id']);

    while($childs = mysql_fetch_assoc($qChilds))
    {
        echo '<a href="?id='.$childs['id'].'">'.$childs['title'].'</a><br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps I can try to understand your question using an example. Consider, your table has the following records:

```
id title parent
1  a     0
2  b     0
3  c     0
4  a1    1
5  a2    1
6  b1    2
7  c1    3
8  c2    3
9  c3    3
```

Your above code will generate an output like this in the first run, i.e. a list of all parent categories and their child categories:

```
a
  a1
  a2
b
  b1
c
  c1
  c2
  c3
```

Your requirement is that if someone clicks on a parent category, say "a", it should show only a's child categories and hide all child categories of "b" and "c". Right?

Additionally, if someone clicks on the child category, it should still show the same result as if someone clicked on the parent page.

If my understanding on your requirement is correct, you can fix your code by passing the parent-id instead of child-id in the child-link, as indicated below:

```
$gParents = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db.pages WHERE parent = 0');
while($parents = mysql_fetch_assoc($gParents))
{
    echo '<a href="?id='.$parents['id'].'">'.$parents['title'].'</a><br />';

    $qChilds = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db.pages WHERE parent = '.$parents['id'].' AND parent = '.$_GET['id']);

    while($childs = mysql_fetch_assoc($qChilds))
    {
        echo '<a href="?id='.$parents['id'].'">'.$childs['title'].'</a><br />';
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, if it isn't absolutely required, perhaps it will make sense to not give any link on the child categories?

Hope the above helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this wouldn't quite work, as I need to display the content of the child page (Another field) after the user clicks a child page. Currently they would see the content of the parent page, and the child page link navigates to the parent page.

The child pages still need to be displayed on the parent and child pages, whilst also displaying the selected page's content(s)

Comment: @user2443394, I'm not sure I quite follow your question/requirement

Comment: The table structure in your previous post is exactly what I'm trying to achive. My aim is to create a vertical page menu using <ul>'s. Upon a user clicking a parent menu item, they will taken to a different page where the content of the selected page will be displayed. Any child pages will be displayed as <li>'s of a child <ul> in the menu, underneath the relevent paten in the menu. Child pages need to be visible only when the parent page, or child pages belonging to the parent have been selected.

Comment: I'm guessing I will need to check if the user is in a parent or child page of the parent, in order to show any relevent child pages.

Comment: do you understand what I'm trying to do now?

Comment: @user2443394, I'd suggest that you please try to implement and run the code block I'd given above. It may perhaps give you the desired output